# Launching Google Chrome from within Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm pulling my hair out over this since I'm already searching for a solution on it for a few days.

The problem is that when no instance of Chrome is currently opened and I press the Google Chrome Button to launch my web application, Chrome opens a new window on a gray screen. I can't load any pages, not even the settings page. It only occures when I do it from Visual Studio in Administrator mode. When an active instance of chrome is already opened, it will successfully open on that instance in a new tab. When I open the Chrome exe in the program files or via my desktop shortcut, it also works fine. It seems to only occur when launched from within VS administrator modus.

Steps to reproduce in my case:

- Open VS in Administrator
- Close all instances of Chrome
- Launch web application in Chrome
- New Chrome window opens with unresponsive gray screen:

[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z1pC.png)

I've already tried:

- Repairing VS
- Reinstalling Chrome

Anyone already encountered this problem and has a solution?

Cheers

Comment: did you try CTRL + F5 when a new Chrome instance launches? This will tell if the stylesheet is not being loaded properly. Also, how does it behave in other browsers?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue for a day or so and was really getting on my nerves!

I tried a few things:

- Loading Chrome in Administrator mode (didn't work)
- Loading Chrome independently, i.e. not getting Visual Studio to debug directly in Chrome, then pointing it to my app (didn't work)
- Setting Chrome to always run in Admin mode (didn't work)

Finally I set Chrome's Compatibility settings to run Windows 8 and it seems to work now! Even from VS firing it directly into Debug mode.

I'm running

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Visual Studio 2015 Pro

It's worth noting this issue NEVER happened in Visual Studio 2013 Community.

Hope that helps

[Chrome compatibility settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4FvF.png)